# select distinct two columns width other columns

Tags: mysql, distinct

quick example

```
sender_id  ||  receiver_id 
 25        ||     30 
 25        ||     32 
 30        ||     25 
 30        ||     20 
 20        ||     25
```

I want output like this:

```
sender_id  ||  receiver_id
   25      ||     30
   25      ||     32
   30      ||     20
   20      ||     50
```

what query should be 
any one can help 
note: i want to select another columns in the selection

Comment: What if the other columns that you want to select are different? Which row's columns will be returned?

Comment: other columns ( data, message )

Comment: note in the output i didn't select (30||25) because i first tow (25||30) so i didn't third row

Comment: Is there a primary key column like an id, or a datetime column which can be used to check which row is the 1st row in case of rows like 25,30 and 30,25?

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.sender_id < t.receiver_id
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where receiver_id = t.sender_id and sender_id = t.receiver_id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r14kjpDb1amN5b79ei37nm/0).
Results:

```
| sender_id | receiver_id |
| --------- | ----------- |
| 25        | 30          |
| 25        | 32          |
| 30        | 20          |
| 20        | 25          |
```

Comment: i want to make screen shot to you

Comment: https://files.fm/u/vhkkcxnt#/view/db.jpg
please see this screen shot

Comment: focus on first row , last row

Comment: see the previous like 
https://files.fm/u/vhkkcxnt#/view/db.jpg (this is)
first record (30||25) and last record (25||30)

Comment: From the sample data in the image you posted what is your expected output?

Comment: (25||30) = (30||25)  and so on
i want to delete duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

If you just want compare sender_id and receiver_id ....... I think you must do a JOIN with a subquery like this

```
select * from TABLE t 
JOIN (     
      SELECT DISTINCT sender_id, receiver_id FROM table_two  
) subqquery ON subquery.key = t.key
```

I hope help you

Answer (score 0):

Try 
this query to get your result,

```
select distinct a.sender_id,a.receiver_id
    from sen_rev a
    left join sen_rev b
    on a.sender_id=b.receiver_id
    where a.receiver_id<> b.sender_id
    order by a.sender_id;
```